# Is a converted Jew with no Jewish ancestral background or lineage considered a Jew?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

I wonder if a gentile converts to Judaism and has no Jewish family background at all then is that person considered a Jew? Are there any sects in Judaism that have this restriction?

Any citations or evidence from the Torah, Talmud or Mishnah would be appreciated.

Comment: The question shown as duplicate does not apply to this question. This question deals with someone who is definitely Jewish, having converted according to halacha. The answer though is that there is no such thing as *second class* in Judaism. Once a person has converted, he or she is fully Jewish like Rus the ancestress of King David and the mashiach.

Comment: Is a converted jew a jew?

Comment: a person who converts to judaism through a valid conversion process, according to all the minute details of jewish law is considered 100% jewish even if he has no jewish ancestry.

Comment: It depends on what you refer to and your definitions of certain terms. Jewish could refer to someone who is a jew, but is could also be used to refer to someone practicing judaism. Normally those would go hand in hand, yet these days some jews aren’t jewish (i.e practicing judiasm) but christians for example or atheists.

Comment: I think one who is converted is definitely considered jewish (one of us, the Tenach seems to make this clear) , but I’m not so sure if they are considered to Jews (i.e. by bloodline). By the way the term jew or jewish aren’t used in the time of Moshe for example, people were Israelites, yet some were considered ezrach while others within the religious community/congregation of faith, had different titles described to them.